# Nougat on Nexus 4

Tags: 7.0-nougat

**How to get android 7.0 on nexus 4**
Can anyone tell me how can i get android 7.0 on my nexus 4 which is officially not included for android 7.0

Comment: Did you attempt to search? My first Google search result takes me to [this] (http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/orig-development/wip-aosp-7-0-nougat-t3448444) XDA page. BTW, you will not get an official ROM - hope you are not asking for that!

Comment: @Narayanan Clicked inside thinking of posting just this, and saw your comment. Make it an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no official (means approved by Google) Android 7.0 Nougat version for Nexus 4.

But there are unofficial attempts, for example [THIS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/orig-development/wip-aosp-7-0-nougat-t3448444).

Always check the feature/bug list to a Custom ROM. In the linked ROM the Camera can't able to make videos in 1080p only 720p, it is a known bug so helpfully there will be an update to fix it soon.

Credits: @[Narayanan](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/orig-development/wip-aosp-7-0-nougat-t3448444)